# Wrong calendar displaying after server crash

Tags: php, mysql

Few days ago server crashed and was down for few hours, after server become available, my calendar started to display wrong data. It had to show me current month and 5 next(half a year in total). Server data is correct. Any ideas whats wrong with calendar? Does mysql server time can make my calendar show wrong data?

```
    if (!isset($_MONTH))
    $_MONTH = 6;

     if (isset($_POST['subscribe_month']))
    $_MONTH = $class->_dig($_POST['subscribe_month']);

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT d.header, d.id FROM " . $class->_cfg['pfx'] . "workshops as w
    LEFT JOIN " . $class->_cfg['pfx'] . "workshops_date as wd ON wd.cid=w.id
    LEFT JOIN " . $class->_cfg['pfx'] . "dictionary as d ON d.id=wd.city
    WHERE w.public='1' and wd.public='1' and wd.date_end>='" . date("Y-m-d") . "' a

nd wd.predprosomtr='0' " . $where . " ORDER BY d.rang");
$CityList = array();
while ($_sql = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $CityList[$_sql['id']] = $_sql['header'];
}

if ($Fcity && $Fcity != 0)
    $where.=" and d.id=" . $Fcity . "";
elseif ($_POST['city'] && $class->_dig($_POST['city']) > 0)
    $where.=" and d.id=" . $class->_dig($_POST['city']) . "";

if ($CitySearch != 0)
    $where.=" and wd.city=" . $CitySearch . " ";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT w.header, w.direction, w.subheader, wd.colsmonth, wd.is_new, wd.public_date_finish, wd.p_date_finish, w.aliaslink, wd.aliaslink as wd_aliaslink, w.direction, wd.city, wd.date_start, d.header as city_name, wd.date_end, wd.cid, wd.id as wd_id, w.id as w_id FROM " . $class->_cfg['pfx'] . "workshops as w
LEFT JOIN " . $class->_cfg['pfx'] . "workshops_date as wd ON wd.cid=w.id
LEFT JOIN " . $class->_cfg['pfx'] . "dictionary as d ON d.id=wd.city
WHERE w.public='1' and wd.public='1' and wd.date_end>='" . date("Y-m-d") . "' and w.direction<>'' and wd.predprosomtr='0' " . $where . " ORDER BY wd.date_start, wd.city");
//$output.=$where;
$month = 12;
$year = date("Y");

while ($_sql = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $view = true;

    if ($_sql['public_date_finish'] == '1' && $_sql['p_date_finish'] < date("Y-m-d"))
        $view = false;

    if ($view) {
        $arWorkshops[$_sql['w_id']] = $_sql;
        if (!isset($arWorkshopsCity[$_sql['cid']][$_sql['city']]) && $_sql['city'] > 0)
            $arWorkshopsCity[$_sql['cid']][$_sql['city']] = $_sql['city'];

        if (isset($arWorkshopsDate[$_sql['cid']]['count']))
            $arWorkshopsDate[$_sql['cid']]['count'] = $arWorkshopsDate[$_sql['cid']]['count'] + 1;
        else
            $arWorkshopsDate[$_sql['cid']]['count'] = 1;

        $direct = explode('#', $_sql['direction']);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($direct); $i++) {
            if (trim($direct[$i]) != '') {
                $arDirectionList[$direct[$i]] = $direct[$i];
            }
        }
        //$arDirectionList[$_sql['direction']]=$_sql['direction'];
        if (!isset($arWorkshopsDate[$_sql['cid']][ceil($class->convert_date($_sql['date_start'], '.', "month"))]))
            $arWorkshopsDate[$_sql['cid']][ceil($class->convert_date($_sql['date_start'], '.', "month"))] = $_sql;

        if ($class->convert_date($_sql['date_start'], '.', "month") < $month && $class->convert_date($_sql['date_start'], '.', "year") == $year) {
            $month = $class->convert_date($_sql['date_start'], '.', "month");
            $year = $class->convert_date($_sql['date_start'], '.', "year");
        }
        //if($class->convert_date($_sql['date_start'], '.', "year")==(date("Y")+1))$year=$class->convert_date($_sql['date_start'], '.', "year");
        //$output.=$_sql['header']."-".$_sql['date_start']."-".$_sql['wd_id']."<br>";
    }
}


//var_dump($arWorkshopsDate[185]);
$output.='<table class="table"><tr><th width="60">&nbsp;</th><th class="first" style="width:auto">Название</th>';
if ($_MONTH == 12)
    $w = "5%"; else
    $w = "9%";

for ($i = $month; $i < ($month + $_MONTH); $i++) {
    if ($year == date("Y"))
        $m = $i;else
        $m++;

    if ($m <= 12 && $year == date("Y")) {
        $output.='<th class="month" style="width:' . $w . '">' . $class->convert_date($m, '.', "myear") . ' <span>' . $year . '</span></th>';
    } else {
        if ($m > 12) {
            $m = 1;
            $year = $year + 1;
        }
        $output.='<th class="month" style="width:' . $w . '">' . $class->convert_date($m, '.', "myear") . ' <span>' . $year . '</span></th>';
    }
}
$output.='  <th style="width:10%">';
if ($typeblock == 'webinars')
    $output.='Формат';
else
    $output.='Город';
$output.='</th></tr>';
if (isset($arWorkshops)) {
    //foreach($arWorkshops as $LO=>$listOrd){
    foreach ($arWorkshops as $k => $value) {
        if (!$direction || $direction == 0)
            $direction2 = $class->_direction($value['direction']);
        else
            $direction2 = $direction;

        foreach ($arWorkshopsCity[$k] as $LO => $listOrd) {
            $output2 = "";
            $link_date = "";
            $pt = 0;
            $m_nth = ceil($month);
            $is_new_class = '';
            for ($i = ceil($month); $i < ($month + $_MONTH); $i++) {
                if ($m_nth > 12)
                    $m_nth = 1;

                if (isset($arWorkshopsDate[$k][$m_nth]) && $arWorkshopsDate[$k][$m_nth]['city'] == $LO) {
                    $pt++;
                    if ($pt == 1)
                        $city_name = $arWorkshopsDate[$k][$m_nth]['city_name'];
                    //if(isset($_TYPE) && $_TYPE!=0)$output.='<td class="date"><a href="/'.$typeblock.'/'.$value['aliaslink'].'/'.$arWorkshopsDate[$k][$i]['wd_aliaslink'].'/">';
                    //else

                    if (($arWorkshopsDate[$k][$m_nth]['is_new'] == '1') || ($arWorkshopsDate[$k][$m_nth + 1]['is_new'] == '1')) {
                        $is_new_class = " it_is_new";
                    } else {
                        $is_new_class = '';
                    }

                    $output2.='<td class="date"><a href="/' . $typeblock . '/' . $arDictionaryID[$direction2]['aliaslink'] . '/' . $value['aliaslink'] . '/' . $arWorkshopsDate[$k][$m_nth]['wd_aliaslink'] . '/">';
                    $link_date = '/' . $typeblock . '/' . $arDictionaryID[$direction2]['aliaslink'] . '/' . $value['aliaslink'] . '/' . $arWorkshopsDate[$k][$m_nth]['wd_aliaslink'] . '/';
                    if ($arWorkshopsDate[$k][$m_nth]['colsmonth'] > 0)
                        $output2.=$class->convert_date($arWorkshopsDate[$k][$m_nth]['date_start'], '.', "day_month") . "</a><br />" . $arWorkshopsDate[$k][$m_nth]['colsmonth'] . " мес.";
                    elseif ($arWorkshopsDate[$k][$m_nth]['date_start'] == $arWorkshopsDate[$k][$m_nth]['date_end'])
                        $output2.=$class->convert_date($arWorkshopsDate[$k][$m_nth]['date_start'], '.', "day_month") . "</a>";
                    else
                        $output2.=$class->convert_date($arWorkshopsDate[$k][$m_nth]['date_start'], '.', "day_month") . "<br />-" . $class->convert_date($arWorkshopsDate[$k][$m_nth]['date_end'], '.', "day_month") . "</a>";
                    $output2.='</td>';
                }else {
                    $output2.='<td></td>';
                }
                $m_nth++;
            }

            if (($arWorkshopsDate[$k][$m_nth]['is_new'] == '1')) {
                $is_new_class = " it_is_new";
            }

            $output.='<tr><td class="' . $is_new_class . '">&nbsp;</td><td>';
            //if(isset($_TYPE) && $_TYPE!=0)$output.='<a href="/'.$typeblock.'/'.$value['aliaslink'].'/'.$value['wd_aliaslink'].'/"><strong>'.$value['header'].'</strong></a>';
            //else
            if ($pt == 1 && $arWorkshopsDate[$k]['count'] == 1)
                $link = $link_date;
            else
                $link = '/' . $typeblock . '/' . $arDictionaryID[$direction2]['aliaslink'] . '/' . $value['aliaslink'] . '/';

            $output.='<a href="' . $link . '"><strong>' . $value['header'] . '</strong>';
            if (trim($value['subheader']) != '')
                $output.=': ' . $value['subheader'] . '';
            $output.='</a>';
            $output.='</td>';
            $output.=$output2;
            $output.=' <td class="city">' . $city_name . '</td></tr>';
        }
    }
//}
}
$output.='</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. By default some "good" coder made it show only from 12th month in `$month = 12;`
I just changed it to `$month = date("m");` And this solved my issue